# Encoding 'UTF-8' throws an exception in macOS

Tags: python, glove

I'm trying to read a GloVe file: `glove.twitter.27B.200d.txt`. I have the next function to read the file:

```
def glove_reader(glove_file):
    glove_dict = {}
    with open(glove_file, 'rt', encoding='utf-8') as glove_reader:
        for line in glove_reader:
            tokens = line.rstrip().split()
            vect = [float(token) for token in tokens[1:]]
            glove_dict[tokens[0]] = vect
    return glove_dict
```

The problem is that I get the next error:

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xea in position 0: invalid continuation byte`

I tried with `latin-1` but it didn't work. Throws me the next error:
`ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Ù\x86'`

I also tried change `'rt'` with  `'r'` and `'rb'`. I think is a problem of macOS because in Windows didn't throw me this error. Can someone please help me to know why I can't read this file.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Glove, but you might want to confirm the file's encoding with `file glove.twitter.27B.200d.txt`, cause it doesn't seem to be UTF-8.

Comment: @Luis Miguel It may be helpful to include an example GloVe file which is valid and that triggers the error mentioned above.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41272247/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xea

Comment: Can you retest `open(glove_file, 'r', encoding='latin-1')` and report any errors it gives?  It definitely should not return a utf-8 error.

Comment: @whydoubt I update the question with the error.

Comment: AFAICT, the file does contains proper utf-8 data (unless your copy got altered somehow).  Do you get a traceback with the error, that can tell you what line failure occurs at?

Comment: If you use `open(glove_file, 'rb')` you should not get any encoding-related errors, as everything should be done as `bytes`.  If your keys in `glove_dict` need to be of type `str`, then you will need to perform a decode at that point: `glove_dict[tokens[0].decode()] = vect`.  If that causes an error, I would wrap it with try/except and print tokens[0] on exception to see what bytes sequence is causing it to fail.